# Shiro Session management for Spring web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro, session-management

I have a web application that I would to deploy on multiple servers. I would like to take advantage of shiros session management to persist session into an external datastore. I have done everything in the documentation but somehow, my spring beans are not persisted across requests so I end up getting a Null pointer on an object I had initialized in the previous request. Below is my config. I am using shiro 1.2.4 and spring 3.1.4.RELEASE.

Spring context xml file:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="sessionCacheManager"/>
    <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="sessionCacheManager" class="com.my.package.SessionCacheManager"/>

<bean id="sessionDAO" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO"/>

<bean id="sessionManager"  class="org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager">
    <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO"/>
</bean>
```

Below is my web.xml config:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <description>My custom Servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>myservletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.package.CustomDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have the flowing in my code:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {}
```

Now in my controller I do have something like following:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @Autowired
   private MyClass myClass;
}
```

Now when request 1 comes in and i do myClass.setName("this is a test") I expect it to save it in the bean in the session so that when request 2 comes in and I do myClass.getName() i will get "this is a test". But that is not what is happening, when the second request comes in and I do myClass.getName() it returns null. It looks like nothing is being persisted to session. I thought it may be that spring isnt proxying the session correctly but when I do SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession and print the shiro session attributes, I see scopedTarget.myClass as part of the keys stored in session but it seems like shiro isnt persisting it correctly or some config is wrong.